# How can a user login on a wordpress page?

Tags: pages, login, bbpress

I am running a wordpress page and looking for a way to implement a forum ([bbPress](https://bbpress.org/)) on one of my pages. I only want registered users (they are added by the admin manually) to post to the forum. I am able to set up the forum but I am not able to create a topic or post anything since You must be logged in to create new topics.

The questions that I now have are:

1. How can I implement the functionality for the page to ask the user to log in if no user is currently logged in? And
2. how does a user stays logged in? If I log myself in via wp-login.php

   - Going to myurl.com/wp-login.php
   - Entering my username and password and pressing Log In (the site then redirects me to my index page)

   the site apparently does not recognize me as a user. I tested that by putting this

   ```
   <?php
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
   } else {
       echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
   }
   ?>
   ```

   on my index page (index.php) and it always echoed `Welcome, visitor!`

The Theme that I am using is called [Peekaboo](http://themeforest.net/item/pekaboo-for-wordpress-children-theme-template/409980) and the Plugins I am using are

- bbPress,
- Contact Form 7 and
- Maintenance.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestion/link etc.

Comment: You need to provide more information about which forum have you implemented, what do you mean with "If I log myself in via wp-login.php the site apparently does not recognize me as a user" and so on. Your question, as it is, is very difficult to answer and very board.

Comment: @cybmeta I elaborated my question a little. I am sorry that not the most relevant information is in the question but I am new to wordpress^^

Comment: The forum settings in bbPress allow to set private forums only logged in registered users. See [getting started with bbPress](http://codex.bbpress.org/getting-started-with-bbpress/). You should ask in the bbPress support forums. It is more appropiate for your question.

Comment: @cybmeta I don't think it is a bbPress issue since the only reason I cannot use the forum is due to the fact that my site doesn't recognize me as being logged in.

Comment: So, you can not log in your site?

Comment: @cybmeta Correct :) (see point number 2)

Comment: I saw your point number 2. You said "If I log myself in via wp-login.php" then "the site apparently does not recognize me as a user". So, you said you can log in but have problems after you have logged. I'm sorry but I still don't understand your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18643/discussion-between-woltan-and-cybmeta).

Comment: @cybmeta I see how the question is ambiguous and restated the logging in part. I hope things are now clearer. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: Can you use WordPress admin? Do you see WP toolbar on front end when logged in?

Comment: @Rarst Yes I can use the admin panel with all its features.

Comment: @Woltan Where are you putting this code?

Comment: @GauravPareek I put this code on the `index.php` page after which the echoed text appeared in the upper left corner. (I edited the question to reflect that)

Comment: Are you using caching?  If so you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @user42826 I am not sure if I use caching. At least not intentional. (The site is not very sophisticated, if that vague statement helps...)

Comment: There are many ways to cache, either at the server level or in WP.  In WP you would most likely use plugins like W3 total cache or Supercache.  One way to test is to change your index.php and load it immediately afterwards.  For example, change 'Welcome, visitor!' to 'Welcome, new visitor!'.  If you see the old message you have some type of caching enabled.

Comment: @user42826 The only plugins installed are bbPress, Contact Form 7 and Maintenence. The theme I am using is called Peekaboo. (I'll add that to the question as it may be related to it.)

Comment: Did you try changing the message in index.php and seeing if you see it immediately?  Also when you log in is it over https?  There could be a problem if you are switching between http and https.

Comment: @user42826 Yes I gave it a try and the altered message appears. So we can rule caching out. Also there is no https involved neither in the registration nor in the page itself.

Comment: Last two things I can think of.  Change to a default theme and modify index.php with your code bit above.  It should work. Last thing, turn on WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error you received seems to be associated with the zipped plugin. May be when you downloaded the "sidebar login" plugin, it got corrupted. Not sure what caused the problem but it is working absolutely fantastic on my site.
Would suggest you to download it from WordPress Plugins directory and then try uploading to your server again.Get more details at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/front-end-user-registration-login-profile-posting

Comment: I disabled all the plugins and installed them again. It appears, that it is not a plugin malfunction. Maybe the theme? I have absolutely no clue anymore...

Comment: To check if it's your theme, just switch to a WP theme like 2012

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is a PHP program. This means that it starts up when it receives a HTTP request from the internet, it processes the request, sends the reply, and then shuts down. The system doesn't keep track of who is "logged in". The individual user keeps their credentials [username/password] in a cookie on their local browser. The cookie gets sent to the server, Wordpress decides if it likes the credentials, and then replies with content suitable to a "logged in" user, or for a user who is not logged in. Your code, which you just inserted into the index.php, isn't being properly "hooked" ['hook' is a term you need to look up] into Wordpress. It's outside the normal process of how Wordpress works. You should put code like this somewhere in a theme or a plugin, and then properly hook into an action that comes after users are logged in. Here is the reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference.

Next time, try to focus your question to be one, specific, narrow question. You should ask multiple, smaller questions instead of one large one. Good luck!